# ¿Cómo hago que mi código HTML se vea en mi página tal cual sin obedecer las marcas?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Estoy creando la página de ayuda de mi sitio web, en la que doy **instrucciones** a mi usuario sobre el uso correcto de una nueva librería que estoy creando. Estoy imprimiendo el texto con ayuda de **JavaScript** ya que es la única manera que tengo de traducir mi página. Una vez aclarado esto, comienzo:

Escribo esta instrucción a mi usuario:

```
<li>
   <b>Importa la librería a tu archivo HTML:<br />
   <span class="code">
      <script src="(ubicación del archivo)/tmnwtools-v1.0.js"></script>
   </span>
</li>
```

Todo bien, hasta que me doy cuenta de que al abrir la página, el código HTML dentro de mi `<span class="code">` es **ejecutado** por el navegador (intenta **cargar** una librería que por nada del mundo va a existir; es para dar instrucciones), y lo que necesito es que el texto dentro de mi `<span class="code">` salga **tal cual lo escribí**. Intenté usar `<pre>` pero no funcionó.

¿Alguien sabe si existe una manera de prevenir que se ejecute el código HTML dentro de cierto elemento y salga el texto tal cual en la página?

Gracias por tu atención y espero me puedas ayudar. ¡Ten un buen día! ☀️

Comment: <pre>
    <code>
          <span>Importa la librería a tu archivo HTML: &lt; script src ="(ubicación del archivo)/tmnwtools-v1.0.js" &gt;</span>
    </code>
  </pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el codigo html no se interprete cambiamos los > y los < de las etiquetas como en el ejemplo que te dejo:

```html
    <li><b>Importa la librería a tu archivo HTML:&lt;br /&gt;&lt;span 
        class="code"&gt;&lt;script src="(ubicación del archivo)/tmnwtools- 
        v1.0.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</li>
```

[Fuente](http://www.jpromero.com/2010/09/mostrar-etiquetas-html-sin-que-sean.html)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Modifiqué un poquito el código porque convertiste de más, pero me ayudaste a entender el concepto. ¡Ten un lindo día (o noche)!

Comment: Ok, que bueno que te pude ayudar. feliz día!